# File 'PATH\bin\Release\APPNAME\Controls\xyz.xaml' could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, dll

I created a new class library for windows store apps and within this library I created a Usercontrol in a folder named 'Controls'.

I use this class library in another project (especially this controls mentioned above) and everytime I try to run this project a weird error occurs:

> "Payload file 'C:\PATH TO CLASSLIBRARY FOLDER\bin\Release\LIBRARYNAME\Controls\Usercontrol.xaml' could not be found"

So I opened my library's folder and looked up this path.
The path described in the error message does not exists but if you would replace
`\bin\Release\LIBRARYNAME\Controls\Usercontrol.xaml` with `\bin\Release\Controls\Usercontrol.xaml` then there is the wanted file.
Then I simply copied the `\Controls\` folder containing Usercontrol.xaml and pasted it into the newly created folder `\LIBRARYNAME\Controls\Usercontrol.xaml`.
Now this error doesn't occur anymore but I don't want to do this copy-paste action everytime I modify Usercontrol.xaml?!

Does anybody know why this happens? Is there a way to avoid my inconvenient solution?
Thanks for help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some further researching with the exacty english error message (worked with german vs2012 by then) it seems that this is a bug in Visual Studio.

More info about this:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/51111470-8a86-44d4-acb8-e268afa7564e/